# List of Friends fron Facebook which have been to specific place

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to retrieve the list of friends who have visited a particular place using graph api javascript sdk.

For example: Sam, Nike and 7 others have been to this place.

Is there any API call which I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get data of users who authorized your App. There is no way to get any data of friends who did not authorize the App. Check out the API reference to find out what data you can get from authorized users: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user

Answer (score 1):

As @luschn already said, this is not possible with the current version of the Graph API.

You might have a look at what **IS** possible concerning social context here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/social-context/v2.4

Comment: Hey Tobi, As per your given link

friends_tagged_at (for places) - The friends of a the calling user who have been tagged at that place.

can this be used to get the details what I am looking for?

Comment: That could maybe be sufficient, depending on your use case. But have you read that `Only friends who use the requesting app will be returned.
`. This means that all 9 people of your example would need to use the app  to get them returned...

Comment: yes. It says that but ,total_count is "The total_count of friends tagged at this place, including those not using the app"

Comment: Yes, but you won't get the friend's names for example. Only the overall number

Comment: The JS request call requires page-id. is there anyway to retrieve page id by page name or page title. and later use that page id to this JS request.

Comment: Please have a look at the docs before asking those questions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search Using the search function of the FB docs should give you most answers